# Fitting a glmmTMB mode with pre-defined coefficients

Tags: glmmtmb

I'm working on an analysis in which I conducted multimodel inference and model averaging using glmmTMB, which I used for the ordered beta distribution and I would like to stick with. I dredged the global model, took the 95% confidence set, and calculated the average coefficient for each predictor. Now, however, I would like to figure out how well this averaged model explains the data. Is there a way of making or fitting a model object with predefined coefficients? I would then use this in k-fold cross-validation, and/or in performance::r2, but either way I need a model object.

Here is an example:

```
data = data.frame(response = c(0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.75),
         varA = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 1, 0.8),
         varB = c(-0.4, -1.3, 0.3, 1.6, 0.8),
         varC = c(-1.2, -0.1, 0.5, 1.2, -0.3))

model <- glmmTMB(response ~ varA + varB + varC,
                 family = glmmTMB::ordbeta(link = "logit"),
                 data = data, na.action = na.pass)

model_dredge <- MuMIn::dredge(model)

#find cut-off for 95% confidence set
value <- 0

for (i in 1:nrow(model_dredge)){
  if (value < 0.95){
    value <- value + as.numeric(model_dredge$weight[i])
    model_cutoff <- i 
  } else {}
}

conf_set <- model_dredge[1:model_cutoff, ]

## Weighted mean coefficients (Int, A, B, C)
coeffs <- vapply(c(1, 3, 4, 5), \(i) { 
  stats::weighted.mean(conf_set[,i], conf_set$weight, na.rm = TRUE)
}, numeric(1))
```

Ultimately, I end up with a set of coefficients that are similar to, but different than, my global model. I thought about going into the global model object and manually overwriting the variable coefficients in the object (eg, `model$fit$par[1]` is the intercept, `model$fit$par[2]` is varA, and so on.) However, there are other parameters that I don't know how to obtain without refitting the model with the new averaged coefficients, one labelled "betad" and two labelled "psi".

Could someone please suggest either a) how to fit the model using varA_coeff, varB_coeff, and varC_coeff, b) how to figure out "betad" and "psi" without refitting the model, or c) an alternative way to evaluate the fit of my averaged model?

Sincerely,
Corrina

Comment: Welcome to CV. You have a mistake in your definition of `data` which is a single vector but should probably be a `data.frame`, the number of rows don't match however. When I remove either the first or the last `response` the model doesn't converge. I'm also assuming you wanted to calculate your `varB_coeff` on `cond(varB)`, and the same for `C`. '`95_conf_set`' is not a valid variable name in R however - did you even run your own example?

Comment: Hi @PBulls, you're right, sorry - I was trying to squeeze in some work while family is visiting and was rushing, I should've properly checked it. I fixed the typos, but I looked up the convergence error and I'm not sure how to fix it as the docs say it is "hard to diagnose".

Comment: It's most likely because you have responses that are equal to 0 or 1, which the beta distribution doesn't support. If I replace these by e.g. `response[3:4] <- c(0.3, 0.6)` the model converges. You'll also have to include some kind of non-default `na.action` somewhere for `MuMIn::dredge` to stop complaining, I've edited in these changes and will write up an answer. I've also taken the liberty to shorten your coefficient code.

Comment: @PBulls I'm using an ordered beta which does support both 0s and 1s, and my actual models with data with 0s and 1s do converge

Comment: That might be but the data you provided didn't. This seems to be a zero/one-inflated beta regression under the hood, fitting three joint models on just 5 observations is asking a bit much. That also has implications for the answer: the conditional means are not going to come from the mean model, but also the zero- and one-inflation parts. You'll have to 'dredge' these as well. I was already not very convinced this was a good idea & now I'm even more pessimistic; the best fit for a given set of predictors is that model after all, not some pool. Did you consider ridge/lasso or similar?

Comment: Are you concerned solely because of 3 models and 5 observations? My real data is ~2,500 observations, I just made a small dummy set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the linear predictor, response residuals (others are not defined for this link family), and possibly some kind of [pseudo-R2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231365/calculating-a-pseudo-r2-value-when-deviance-is-negative/) from your coefficients. Anything beyond that will require a *very* deep dive into the guts of `glmmTMB` and this is already very close to a programming question which is off-topic on this site.

Reconstructing the linear predictor is easy enough: just multiply your averaged coefficients by the design matrix.

```r
linp <- function(A, B, C, beta) beta[1] + A*beta[2] + B*beta[3] + C*beta[4]

## Reconstruct the non-dredged model
orig <- with(data, linp(varA, varB, varC, beta=model$fit$par[1:4]))
> [1] -0.03805171 -1.41477115 -0.76106155  0.34344611  1.15593206

## Note that this matches `predict()`
all.equal(orig, predict(model))
> TRUE

## Do the same for the updated coefficients
dredged <- with(data, linp(varA, varB, varC, beta=coeffs))
> [1]  0.04027557 -0.89044152 -0.02504540  1.20635796  1.38840273
```

These are your fitted values in the log-odds scale. In a pinch you can overwrite `model$fit$par[1:4]` with these coefficients and get the same result using `predict(..., fast=FALSE)`, the other parameters are not required to calculate predicted means.

Calculating predicted responses and residuals is the same as you would for any other model (deviance and Pearson aren't implemented in your chosen link):

```r
expit <- function(x) 1/(1+exp(-x))
y <- data$response

## Response residuals
y - expit(dredged)
> [1] -0.01006753 -0.09101872 -0.19373898 -0.16965390 -0.05033713

## Confirm this matches `resid()` - names differ
all(y - expit(orig) == resid(model, type="response"))
> TRUE
```

The `performance::r2` function you mentioned doesn't seem to know what to do with your original model. You can calculate a pseudo-R2 as described in the link above:

```
x <- model.matrix(model)

## Original coefficients
cor(qlogis(y), x %*% model$fit$par[1:4])**2
> 0.522

## Dredged weighted means
cor(qlogis(y), x %*% coeffs)**2
> 0.242
```

At least in this dummy example it doesn't look like your dredged coefficients did that great. If you need more, such as standard error predictions, that *will* require the `betad`/`psi` parameters in the fit and I couldn't tell you how to update these without refitting the model.